# How match the URL in Python (okay in Atom but run wrong in Pycharm)?

Tags: python, regex

When I learned to crawling pictures, I used the code in the pictures below to find the URL, and it tested good in Atom (I use Atom to try RE only).

But when I put it in Pycharm, only jpg images are pumped out. Why is that?

You can see the details below.

**Atom:**

[image: run in Atom]

**Pycharm:**

[image: run in Pycharm]

Comment: my re is : https://.+?(jpg|gif)

Comment: But on your second screen there are also `gif` items (on selected line).

Comment: Hi Kolyan, I already know the how it went wrong, it is about findall always recognize '()' content first. Thanks

Comment: maybe you can try to use `(https://.+?(jpg|gif))` instead

Comment: yes, this is the right solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`(https://.+?(jpg|gif))`

Just copied my comment, in order to get this question closed.